# Facebook share button not showing in a page rendered by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

My ajax:

```
$("#searchform").on("submit", function () {
    //$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    var data = {
        "action": "test"
    };

    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "search/ajax2.php",
        data: data,

        success: function (data) {

            getData=data;



if(data!=""){
                 $("inner_div").append("Posted On:"+ data[i].postDate +"<div class='fb-share-button' data-href='https://gloopal.com/search2.php?TID="+ tid +"' data-layout='button'></div>")  ; 

            ......................
           ..........................

            }else
{
.........
.......
}
```

php page:

after  opening tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

In other pages I'm including the fb api after body tag and and below in div and it works: bu not in he ajax rendered page: what should I do for it to render?

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://gloopal.com/search2.php?TID=<?php echo $tid; ?>" data-layout="button">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse you need to call `FB.XFBML.parse()`. That is automatically done when the sdk is included. But if the share button is not in the HTML code at that point it can't be parsed. So just call `FB.XFBML.parse()` after you update the HTML.